# How to Create a Tamil Phonetic keyboard inputs in python?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, tamil

**My target:** create a Phonetic Keyboard in the Tamil language, using dictionary key mapping.  **My struggle:**  How to replace my keys with values and set that value to my textbox. ***For Example:*** If I press **"K"** in textbox1, then my textbox1.text will change into the Tamil letter  **"க்"**, if I press **"Ku"** then textbox1.text will be replaced by the Tamil letter **"கு",**, if I press **"kuu"** then textbox1.text will be replaced by the Tamil letter **"கூ"** And then If I press **"m"** then the Tamil letter **"ம்"** will be added to the previous letter **"கூ"** and now textbox1.text becomes **"கூம்"**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

tamil_dict = {"a":{'a':'அ','aa':'ஆ'},
              "k":{'k':'க்','ka':'க','kaa':'கா','ki':'கி','kii':'கீ','ku':'கு','kuu':'கூ'},
              "m":{'m':'ம்','ma':'ம','maa':'மா','mi':'மி','mii':'மீ','mu':'மு','muu':'மூ'},
              "i":{"i":"இ"},
              "e":"ஈ "}


class Keyboard_Dict(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tamil InPut ")

        self.tbox1 = QLineEdit()
        self.tbox1.setFont(QFont('Arial Unicode MS', 10, QFont.Bold))
        self.tbox1.textChanged.connect(self.func_textbox_textchanged)

        self.tbox2 = QLineEdit()
        self.tbox2.setFont(QFont('Arial Unicode MS', 10, QFont.Bold))

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tbox1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tbox2)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.process_txt_temp_letter = ""
        self.process_txt_temp_position = 0
        self.process_letter_found = False
        self.process_letter_temp = False
        self.processed_text =""
    def func_textbox_textchanged(self,txt):
        self.txt_len = len(self.tbox1.text())
        if self.txt_len >= 1:
            self.process_txt_position = self.txt_len-1
            self.process_text_letter = (txt[self.process_txt_position])


            if self.process_letter_found == False:
                if (txt[self.txt_len-1]) in tamil_dict:
                    self.process_letter_found = True
                    self.process_txt_temp_position = (self.txt_len-1)
                    self.process_txt_temp_letter = (txt[self.txt_len-1])
                    self.process_letter_temp = True

            if self.process_letter_temp == True :
                if (txt[self.process_txt_temp_position:]) in tamil_dict[self.process_txt_temp_letter]:
                    self.processed_text =  tamil_dict[self.process_txt_temp_letter][txt[self.process_txt_temp_position:]]
                    print(self.processed_text)
                    # print("jjjjjjjjj",tamil_dict[self.process_txt_temp_letter][txt[self.process_txt_temp_position:]])

                elif (txt[self.process_txt_temp_position:]) not in tamil_dict[self.process_txt_temp_letter]:
                    self.process_txt_temp_position = self.txt_len - 1
                    self.process_txt_temp_letter = (txt[self.process_txt_temp_position])

                    if self.process_txt_temp_letter not in tamil_dict:
                        self.process_letter_temp = False
                        self.process_letter_found = False
                    else:
                        self.processed_text = tamil_dict[self.process_txt_temp_letter][txt[self.process_txt_temp_position:]]
                        print(self.processed_text)
                        # print("ffffff", tamil_dict[self.process_txt_temp_letter][txt[self.process_txt_temp_position:]])
        self.tbox2.setText(self.processed_text)





def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainscreen = Keyboard_Dict()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    mainscreen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**update : 1**
I Have a keys Maps as follows :

```
      *Main character/processed first character : "k"* 
        k     : "Apple"
        ka    : "Bannana"
        kaa   : "Citrus:
        ki    : "Orange"
        kii   : "Pine" 
        *Main character/processed first character : "M"* 
         m     : "is" 
         ma    : "more"
         maa   : "taste"
 *Main character/processed first character : "i"* 
         i     : "world"
         ii    : "earth"

tamil_dict ={"k":{"k":"apple","ka":"bannana","kaa":"citrus","ki":"orange","kii":"pine"},
             "m":{"m":"is","ma":"more","maa":"taste"},
             "i":{"i":"world","ii":"earth"}
            }
```

In my textbox.text, my first character is **"A"**, not found in dictionary, so need not process that character and display as it is.

In my textbox.text, my second input word  is **"k"**, which is found in my dictionery and also **"k"** is the  main Word. Now My processed word is **"A"+"k"**, my textbox is replaced as follows, **"A" + "Apple" = AApple**.

In my textbox.text, my third charcter is **"a"**,  Now my processed word is **"ka"**, its found in dict . so replaced with that equivalent value "Banana". Now My processed word is **"A"+"ka"**, and now my textbox.text as follows : **"A"+"banana" = Abanana.**

In my textbox.text, my fourth charcter is **"a"**, my processed word becomes "**Kaa"** its equvilient value  is **"citrus"**, now my processed word is **"A"+"kaa"** , its equvlient value is **"A"+"citrus" = "Acitrus"**

In my textbox.text my fifth input character  is **"m"**, now my processed word is ****"kaam"****,not found in dictionery. Now we split character "m" and check it in dict, whether its found or not, if Found, then we replace its equvilent value. Now My processed word is **"A"+'kaa'+"m"** and its vaule is **"A"+"citurs"+"is"**, my textbox.text as follows **"Acitrusis"**

sixth input word is "a", now my processed  character is **"A"+"kaa"+"ma"** equvilaent value is **"A"+"citrus"+"more"**. Textbox.text become **"Acitrusmore"**

Now, if I press  charcter **"i"** not found in **"m" set**. so we split **"i"** sepreately and check it in dict, if found, replace that value or leave as it is.

If 7th input character is  **" space bar"** then process will end.

if my 8th input charcter is some english alphabet, once agin start process and replace equvilaent value and so on

**update : 2** For more cleareance :
[image]

Comment: Since I don't fully know the rules, could you tell me what should be obtained by writing the following:  `m ma maa man mu muu muuu mi mii miip mipi`?

Comment: m=ம் , ma =ம, maa = மா ,  mu =மு , muu =மூ ,mi= மி,mii= மீ mipi=மிபி  and so on

Comment: Do it explicitly, maybe for you the rules are clear but not for me. Within the text I have put many of my doubts.

Comment: tamil_dict = {"a":{'a':'A1','aa':'A2'},
              "k":{'k':'K1','ka':'K12','kaa':'K13','ki':'K2','kii':'K21','ku':'K22','kuu':'K23'},
              "m":{'m':'M1','ma':'M12','maa':'M13','mi':'M2','mii':'M21','mu':'M22','muu':'M23'},
              "i":{"i":"I1"},
              "e":"ஈ "} 
if i press "k", then textbox will replace by "K1" if press "k" and "u" simultaneously then  textbox1.text replaced by "K22" and then press "m" now i want to add "M1" to pervious letter ( K22+M1). @eyllanesc

Comment: If I press "kuu" and then "Muu" now my textbox will display  "K23M23" If I press "a" and then "Ki" and then "mu" now my text box will becomes "A1K2M22" @eyllanesc

Comment: simultaneously or consecutively?

Comment: consecutively  @eyllanesc

Comment: If you really want help then give more detail and be careful with the words you use as it can cause confusion (for example "simultaneously or consecutively").

Comment: @eyllanesc. What i need, I explained in my update :1 edit

Comment: The keywords are totally ambiguous. For example, `kii` could be parsed as "Apple+World+World" or "Apple+Earth" or "Orange+World" or "Pine". If you pick one of those as "correct", it then becomes impossible to enter any of the others. So you need to specify a way to indicate the beginning of a keyword. I would suggest capitalising the first letter. So to enter "Orange+World", you would need to type `KiI`.

Comment: @ekhumoro , if we enter "kii"  it equal to   "Kii"  = pine. first letter is "K" and in  dict {"k":{"k":"apple","ka":"bannana","kaa":"citrus","ki":"orange","kii":"pine"},. so kii is equl to "pine"

Comment: @ekhumoro, if my input is "kiii" then my textbox becomes "pineearth"

Comment: @ekhumoro, for more reference , attach  table in my update 2

Comment: No, you don't understand. How do you enter "apple+world"? That would require typing `k`for "apple", and then `i` for "world" - but that also maps to "orange", so it's ambiguous. Why should it be possible to enter "pine+world", but not "apple+world"? It makes no sense.

Comment: If there are rules that mean certain combinations of keys aren't possible in Tamil, you should explain that in your question. The examples using English words have actually confused everything, because it's made it appear that the keys can be freely combined. But I suspect that is not in fact the case for Tamil.

Comment: the Tamil script, like most scripts of the Indian subcontinent, is an abugida, or alphasyllabary (q.v.). It _might_ be necessary, if a separate vowel can immediately follow a grapheme, to mark the absence of the consonant by prepending an ASCII "no consonant" marker. Otherwise a "longest match" algorithm might yield wrong results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that all you need is this:

```py
import re

[...]

TAMIL_DICT = {
    'a':'அ', 'aa':'ஆ',
    'k':'க்', 'ka':'க', 'kaa':'கா', 'ki':'கி', 'kii':'கீ', 'ku':'கு', 'kuu':'கூ',
    'm':'ம்', 'ma':'ம', 'maa':'மா', 'mi':'மி', 'mii':'மீ', 'mu':'மு', 'muu':'மூ',
    'i':'இ',
    'e':'ஈ',  # [...]
}
TAMIL_KEYS = [re.escape(key) for key in sorted(TAMIL_DICT, key=len, reverse=True)]
TAMIL_REGEX = re.compile('|'.join(TAMIL_KEYS))

def convert_to_tamil(s):
    return TAMIL_REGEX.sub(lambda match: TAMIL_DICT[match.group(0)], s)

[...]

    def func_textbox_textchanged(self, txt):
        self.tbox2.setText(convert_to_tamil(txt))
```

Test:

```py
def test_convert_to_tamil():
    test_vectors = [
        ('', ''),
        ('k', 'க்'),
        ('ku', 'கு'),
        ('kuu', 'கூ'),
        ('kuum', 'கூம்'),
        ('VAkuum!', 'VAகூம்!'),
        ('!?', '!?'),
        ('ami', 'அமி'),
        ('aami', 'ஆமி'),
        ('kaaa.', 'காஅ.'),
        ('xka-aau', 'xக-ஆu')
    ]
    for v in test_vectors:
        c = convert_to_tamil(v[0])
        if c != v[1]:
            return f"'{v[0]}': expected '{v[1]}', found '{c}'"
    return "OK"

print(test_convert_to_tamil())
```

Test output:

```sh
OK
```

How it works: The regex scans the input string replacing as it goes. Since what it searches is sorted by decreasing length (`key=len, reverse=True`), it will always replace the longest match, and then continue scanning from the first character following it.

To confirm that sorting by decreasing length is important, try to replace `reverse=True` with `reverse=False`. If you do, and run `test_convert_to_tamil()`, you will get this output:

```sh
'ku': expected 'கு', found 'க்u'
```

Please note that the format of `TAMIL_DICT` is different from the one of your `tamil_dict`.

---

**UPDATE**

The above was based on the understanding that you wanted to use two fields, like you do in your code. It's possible to modify the above code for one field, but at the cost of lots of head scratching caused by the handling of the cursor position, that must also play well with QT's cursor position logic. Anyway, here is an attempt:

```py
TAMIL_DICT = {
    'a':'அ', 'aa':'ஆ',
    'k':'க்', 'ka':'க', 'kaa':'கா', 'ki':'கி', 'kii':'கீ', 'ku':'கு', 'kuu':'கூ',
    'm':'ம்', 'ma':'ம', 'maa':'மா', 'mi':'மி', 'mii':'மீ', 'mu':'மு', 'muu':'மூ',
    'i':'இ',
    'e':'ஈ',  # [...]
}
LATIN_DICT = {val: key for key, val in TAMIL_DICT.items()}

TAMIL_DICT_WITH_CURSOR = {}
for latin, tamil in TAMIL_DICT.items():
    for i in range(1, len(latin)):
        TAMIL_DICT_WITH_CURSOR[f"{latin[:i]}\a{latin[i:]}"] = f"{tamil}\a"
TAMIL_DICT.update(TAMIL_DICT_WITH_CURSOR)

LATIN_DICT_WITH_CURSOR = {}
for tamil, latin in LATIN_DICT.items():
    for i in range(1, len(tamil)):
        LATIN_DICT_WITH_CURSOR[f"{tamil[:i]}\a{tamil[i:]}"] = f"{latin}\a"
LATIN_DICT.update(LATIN_DICT_WITH_CURSOR)

TAMIL_KEYS = [re.escape(key) for key in sorted(TAMIL_DICT, key=len, reverse=True)]
LATIN_KEYS = [re.escape(key) for key in sorted(LATIN_DICT, key=len, reverse=True)]
TAMIL_REGEX = re.compile('|'.join(TAMIL_KEYS))
LATIN_REGEX = re.compile('|'.join(LATIN_KEYS))

def convert_to_tamil(s):
    return TAMIL_REGEX.sub(lambda match: TAMIL_DICT[match.group(0)], s)

def convert_to_latin(s):
    return LATIN_REGEX.sub(lambda match: LATIN_DICT[match.group(0)], s)


class Keyboard_Dict(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tamil Input")
        self.tbox1 = QLineEdit()
        self.tbox1.setFont(QFont('Arial Unicode MS', 10, QFont.Bold))
        self.tbox1.textEdited.connect(self.func_textbox_textedited)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tbox1)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def func_textbox_textedited(self, mixed):
        at = self.tbox1.cursorPosition()
        mixed_a = f"{mixed[:at]}\a{mixed[at:]}"
        latin_a = convert_to_latin(mixed_a)
        tamil_a = convert_to_tamil(latin_a)
        tamil = tamil_a.replace('\a', '')
        if tamil != mixed:
            self.tbox1.setText(tamil)
            self.tbox1.setCursorPosition(tamil_a.find('\a'))
```

Note the use of `textEdited` instead of `textChanged`. This is because `textChanged` would be called on `setText()`.

How it works: On every edit, the text is converted to Latin characters and back to Tamil script (as much as possible) again. The cursor position is temporarily marked in the text as an "alarm" or "bell" character, `\a`, in order to be able to position the cursor after the double conversion. Each conversion either leaves the `\a` where it is, or, if it is in the middle of a recognized group, moves it to the end of the converted group. It could also be moved to another position, but other choices seem to be more problematic, in particular because QT allows the user to delete a modifier, but not to move the cursor to a position between the modified character and the modifier.

Care must be taken to build the mapping in a way that works "back and forth". Remember that at each edit step (which could also be the pasting of a string into the textbox!) the text, in the most common case consisting of all Tamil characters and one Latin character, will be converted to an intermediate representation in all Latin characters, and then back to Tamil characters. The conversion Latin→Tamil→Latin *could*, with certain mappings, not return to the initial representation, and this *could* cause problems (but not necessarily, since the intermediate full Latin representation is not visible to the user). See the comments for an example.

---

**ADDENDUM**

Looking at [this table](https://github.com/thamizha/pykalappai/blob/master/tables/Tamil-phonetic.txt.in), pointed out by @Bala (N.B.: don't use it as it is!), there seems to be the need for entering digits as both ASCII and Tamil digits. There is a simple solution to this:

```py
TAMIL_DICT = {
    [...]
    '`0': '௦',
    '`1': '௧',
    '`2': '௨',
    [...]
    '`9': '௯',
    '`10': '௰',
    '`100': '௱',
    '`1000': '௲',
    [...]
```

*All* other entries in the linked table containing backticks or digits should *not* be added to `TAMIL_DICT`. The effect will be: ASCII digits not preceded by `` ` `` will remain unconverted, ASCII digits preceded by `` ` `` will be converted to Tamil digits (returning to a `` ` ``–ASCII digit sequence in the intermediate Latin representation), `` ` `` not followed by an ASCII digit will remain unconverted. The only downside is that it won't be possible to have a `` ` ``–ASCII digit sequence as a final result (i.e., in the Tamil representation).

This handling of digits can be improved by modifying the two regexes and the code that uses them, for the conversion of a *single* backtick followed by ASCII digits into a sequence of Tamil digits and vice versa (not forgetting the special cases of 10, 100, 1000, and possibly others). To produce `௧௨௩௪௫` you would type `` `12345 `` instead of `` `1`2`3`4`5 ``.

Comment: let me know whether any functionality you need is missing

Comment: everything fine. thanks @Walter Tross

Comment: @walterTross,  how to settext in textbox1 itself. (Not in textbox2)?

Comment: @walterTross, Is it possible to set text in textbox1 ( Bala Comment) ?

Comment: ok, I looked at your code, and there you have two textboxes. It's possible to do something similar in a single textbox, but conserving the cursor position will not be easy. I have an idea for how to do it and will work on it.

Comment: @WalterTross Perfectly worked. great Job. Thank you

Comment: well, I thought I saw some strange cursor behavior, when editing in the middle of the line, but I'm not able to reproduce it now. I'm suspending these tests because of lack of time. Anyway, I don't expect there to be any serious bugs, the code is simple enough to make me confident. The cursor position could only be an occasional nuisance, if any. And I don't expect this nuisance to occur when the cursor is at the end of the line, which is the normal case.

Comment: @WalterTross Your Update code, will not work properly. if the dictionary contains all Tamil alphabets, then it produces an irrelevant result.

Comment: @Bala could you please elaborate, and maybe share the dict?

Comment: @Bala please also read the comment I just added to the question. There are constraints in the mapping between Tamil and ASCII

Comment: @WalterTross Table link https://github.com/thamizha/pykalappai/blob/master/tables/Tamil-phonetic.txt.in

Comment: From your update code, If we type, "t" and "h" its produce "ட்" and "ஹ்". But the expected result is  "த்". But at the same time, If we set text in textbox2, it gives a perfect result.

Comment: self.processed_latin_word = self.processed_latin_word +mixed[-1]
        latin_a = convert_to_latin(self.processed_latin_word)
        tamil_a = convert_to_tamil(latin_a). This gives the expected result, but if we press backspace, its  result is nuisance.  I don't know, how to achieve it.  Expect your updated answer eagerly.

Comment: @Bala I found 2 problems: The first is that in your mapping there are characters that need to be escaped in a regex. I fixed the code adding `re.escape()` where needed. The second problem is that your mapping is not reversible. E.g., `d` and `t` are both mapped to `ட்`. So `t` becomes `ட்`, but then `ட்h` is converted to Latin as `dh`, instead of the `th` you expected, which would be mapped to `த்`. You could make `t` and `d` equivalent _everywhere_ (so that `dh` maps to `த்`, etc.), at your risk.

Comment: anyway, QT is a bit buggy with Tamil characters in QLineEdit fields: if you enter a row of `ட்` (actually two Unicode characters, of which the second is the "vowel killer" dot, a modifier), then you will be able to select the single composite characters, but you won't be able to place the cursor between them, neither with the mouse nor with the arrow keys.

Comment: @Bala another way of fixing the `t`/`d`/`th` problem is to reverse the order of the `t` and `d` blocks in the dict (or in the input file, if you use that). The mapping from Tamil to Latin will be given by the *last* mapping from Latin to Tamil, and this is guaranteed since Python 3.6 (keeping insertion order was a great enhancement to Python). So a `d` will become a `ட்` and then a `t`, and that should be fine. Anyway, that mapping file cannot be used as-is.

Comment: got it.:) @WalterTross

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243387/discussion-between-walter-tross-and-bala).

Comment:  bala and @WalterTross